# Mass Checksumming tool for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, checksum, recursive

I'm looking for a command line tool for windows that will go over a directory tree (recursively) and output a list of all the files in there, and a checksum for each file (can be CRC, MD5, whatever).

Esentially, what I want is to compare 2 big directory trees in 2 machines. I'm planning to take the outputs of running this tool in both, and diffing them to make sure they're identical.

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[hashutils](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hashutils/) and [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) are the best packages I've found on Windows so far.  Both tools are open source from the same author, but HashCheck is a shell extension and hashutils is a set of CLI tools.  In my testing, they're significantly faster than the ported unxutils versions.  (Despite the expectation that they'd be I/O bound.)

I also think that these tools are better than the often-mentioned HashTab, and if I could get to the Ars OpenForum, I'd link a post I wrote up with my justification.

Comment: Ah, I can get to Ars again.  [Comparison of HashCheck & HashTab](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=33861&p=891309)

Comment: Hashutils did the trick. EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: +1 on answer. Nice - for me I would store the output report and then use something like beyond compare comparison tool to compare the current report with the older ones to see what's changed - sound plausible?

Comment: @therobyouknow: Yes, you can do that.  I've done it as a fast way of finding different files on systems where running Beyond Compare on both datasets at once was difficult or impossible.  It's much easier to FTP/copy/email a small txt file around to check against.

Answer (score 1):

Easy in the *nix world. Just grab [the tools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and then make a pipeline of `find`, `sort`, and `md5sum`.

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum
```

Comment: Any ideas for the *indows world?

Comment: Did you try the link?

Comment: The link in IVA's answer is to Windows ported versions of the needed GNU tools. Another option would be cygwin to add a full Linux-a-like environment to Windows, though that would probably be overkill for what you describe soI suggest you give unixtools a go.

Comment: Sorry, no, I didn't follow the link, the start of your comment seemed like the typical "windows sucks" snide remark, I didn't even see the link :-)  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: you should be able to use @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 's answer in mobaxterm. This is free, self-contained single .exe program that provides a Linux-like command line shell on top of Windows - which is what CygWin does too. In fact Mobaxterm is based on Cygwin I believe, but far less messy in terms of setting up, dependencies etc. It really is just download and run.

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander (File -> Calculate checksums). But beware! If all filenames belong to your locale codepage, encoding will be this codepage, otherwise UTF8.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

An alternative is [pyFileFixity](https://github.com/lrq3000/pyFileFixity/), a self-contained Python 2 library, [containing the tool "rfigc.py"](https://github.com/lrq3000/pyFileFixity/#recursive-relative-files-integrity-generator-and-checker-in-python-aka-rfigc). It works on Windows (since my machine runs Windows 7 x64) but it should work on all platforms, and the databases generated on one OS can be used on other OSes (because paths are relative and always uniformized in UNIX style).